# Chrome keeps requesting image specified in css sprite

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, css-sprites

We have a simple css sprite with multiple images that are used for different states of buttons and displaying some rich texts eg. "You matched IMG IMG IMG".

```
.cssinfo_btn_Play_down, .cssinfo_btn_Play_hover, .cssinfo_btn_Play_normal{
background-image: url('pack.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;}
.cssinfo_btn_Play_down{width:311px;height:107px;background-position:-1569px -664px}
.cssinfo_btn_Play_hover{width:311px;height:107px;background-position:-859px -544px}
.cssinfo_btn_Play_normal{width:311px;height:107px;background-position:-1181px -560px}
```

Button

```
<div id="btn-play" ng-class="{'cssinfo_btn_Play_normal': $ctrl.closeState === 1, 'cssinfo_btn_Play_hover': $ctrl.closeState === 2, 'cssinfo_btn_Play_down': $ctrl.closeState === 3}" class="cssinfo_btn_Play_normal" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
```

The wierd thing is that each time style using css sprite is applied, the source image is requested again. Since the image is already loaded, chrome correctly detects that and loads it from memory so there is no network traffic. While this is fairly quick operation, we do notice a small drop in performance. We also tested on Firefox an there are no additional request after initial load.

[Repeated requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aXdh.png)

If we untick background-image in element inspector and tick it back everything works as it should and no additional request are performed.

It seems that the moment css file is edited in browser (through inspector or sources) Chrome correctly updates img lookup table.

For buttons we can create workaround with all states precreated and just changing their visibility, but for texts there are simply to many possible combinations.

Any ideas/suggestions why this is happening in Chrome and how to avoid it?

Comment: Please show the code. Also, only in Chrome?

Comment: @BramVanroy added code. We tested in FF and Chrome, only Chrome had this issue.

Comment: OT: You are using background images to display *text* content ...?

Comment: @CBroe no, it is actually component constructed with text + styled divs